# Checkbox-Field Tree Menu

Tags: routes, nodes, forms

When creating content, I'd like to have something akin to a drop down menu.  You could hover over an item and a list of checkboxes would appear.  Essentially it'd be a Select List with sub-items.  Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Hierarchical Select](https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module. Project page says

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a
>   greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.

It will give you a way to select hierarchical items using select boxes.